# Problema con las url en JSF y richfaces

Tags: java, jsf, url, richfaces

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con JSF y richfaces y tengo el siguiente problema:

Cuando avanzo la página con los "action", la página cambia (todo ok), pero la url no. Pero si le vuelves a dar al mismo botón (porque por ejemplo esté en un menu de navegacion estático), a la segunda vez si que se cambia. Y así siempre... no sé como solucionarlo, he mirado prettyfaces pero lo unico que hace es cambiar la url, pero sigue sin actualizar hasta que le doy dos veces al mismo botón ( ... por ejemplo)...

(utilizo la navegación dinámica básica con faces-config.xml)

Espero respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Podrías agregar código para que te podamos ayudar mejor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una "peculiaridad" derivada de como funciona JSF.

Al hacer click/submit/etc, JSF va a la misma página en la que está para reconstruir el árbol de componentes, meterle los valores que vienen de la página, ejecutar el controlador, etc...

Después de todo eso, procesa la vista destino pero sin cambiar la URL.

Así que, de base, no es un problema, tu servidor funciona correctamente<sup>1</sup>.

Pero hay algunas situaciones en que, de todas formas, conviene tener la URL correcta en el navegador (por ejemplo, para que el usuario la pueda guardar en favoritos). En esos casos (o si te molesta mucho lo de que la URL no coincida) la solución es añadir un parámetro `faces-redirect=true` a las URLs.

Así por ejemplo, si tienes la URL `/inicio.xhtml`, deberías poner `/inicio.xhtml?faces-redirect=true`. Esto hace que, en vez de construir todo el HTML correspondiente a `/inicio.xhtml` desde la llamada que ha invocado al controlador, el navegador reciba un Http Status para hacer un redirect por GET a `/inicio.xhtml`, lo que cambia la URL.

---

<sup>1</sup>O no, pero no por culpa de esto.